# ffmpeg copy command in MLT Multimedia Framework

Tags: ffmpeg, multimedia, mlt

Regards,

What is the equivalent of this ffmpeg command

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -c copy out.mp4
```

in MLT Multimedia Framework [MLT](https://www.mltframework.org/)?

Thank very much!

Answer (score 0):

There is no equivalent MLT command. Currently, MLT only operates on uncompressed data.

Other people have requested this feature in the past, but nobody has taken the time to implement it:

https://github.com/mltframework/mlt/issues/72

https://sourceforge.net/p/mlt/bugs/162/

https://sourceforge.net/p/mlt/bugs/34/

https://sourceforge.net/p/mlt/mailman/message/27023224/